# Why does my while loop ignore the condition and keep going forever?

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script which is supposed to record temperature data of my 2 cpu cores and send it to a file until the file is 10000 lines long, however the 10000 line while loop condition is not doing anything and it keeps going past 10000 lines. Can anyone see why it would do that?

```
lc=`wc -l temps.log2 | grep -o '[0-9]*'`
while [ $lc -lt 10000 ]
do
  sensors | grep ^Core |\
  (
    DATE=$(date +%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S)
    while read LINE
    do
      echo "$DATE $LINE"
    done
  ) >> temps.log2
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lc` isn't being incremented in the loop

Comment: wait, now it is saying `templogv2.sh: 2: [: 1: unexpected operator` and all i did was copy the first line and put it inside the while loop.

Comment: im a moron again. my grep statement was returning more than what I wanted it to.